# Handling .xls file using Robot framework Standalone jar

Tags: excel, automation, robotframework

I am using Robot framework but as I didn't want to have python installed in my machine. Hence I am using the robotframework-3.0.1.jar form maven to run my scripts.

But now I want to access excel form my codes.

I found a library in http://navinet.github.io/robotframework-excellibrary/ but it required python installation. Is there any way out that I can use the robotframework-excellibrary without installing python

Comment: Welcome at [so]. It is expected that questions meet certain criteria. These are described in the [ask] page that I strongly suggest you read. In addition we expect a certain level of effort to already have been spent on your part. This is typically done by showing us the code that you're working on and providing us with descriptions of the things you've tried and the results you've observed. In case of larger blocks of code, simplifying it to a [mcve] helps to understand the issue much quicker on our part.

Comment: Thanks @A.Kootstra for the suggestion. I have updated my post for better understanding best of my knowledge.

Comment: Have you had a look at https://github.com/JeP42/robotframework-easycsvmap?

Comment: But it's for csv file handling. But my requirement is xls. As that's the only file format my application understand

Comment: It seems to me that for this setup with Maven there is no pre created library. This means you have to write your own. This CSV library could be the inspiration you seek.